# form_tag action not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, osx-lion, rubymine

I have this form in my application.html.erb.

```
<%= form_tag(:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts") %>
  <p>
  // code here
  </p>
```

I dont understand why is this getting directed to `posts->create` instead of `posts->index`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, Rails observes and obeys "[RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)" web service architecture. With REST and Rails, there are seven different ways to interact with a server regarding a resource. With your current code, specifying the form's action as index doesn't make sense: Rails' form helpers can either POST, PUT or DELETE.

If you wanted to create a post, then redirect to the index, you can do so in the applicable controller action:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
...

def create
  @post = Post.new

  respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to(:action => 'index') }
end
end
```

While your form would look like:

```
<% form_for @post do |f| %>
  # put whatever fields necessary to create the post here
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be a little mixed up with respect to the uses for each action. Here's a quick summary of typical RESTful usage:

**Index**         -> view a list of items
**New/Edit**      -> form where items are added or edited
**Create/update** -> controller action where items are created/updated

The reason your routes file is not taking you to index is because index is not an action where posts are typically created or updated. The best way is to go RESTful. Unless you have a very unusual situation, the best way to set your system up is probably a little like this:

```
# routes.rb
resources :posts

# application.html.erb (or better: posts/_form.html.erb).
<% form_for @post do |f| %>
<% end %>

# posts controller, whichever action you want to use
def new
  @post = Post.new
end
```

By putting the form in a partial called `form` you can access it in `new`, `edit`, or wherever else you need to manipulate a post in your system.

Comment: I want to print some information regarding posts thats why I routed it to Index. I want to retrieve the values I used in the form of `application.html.erb` and set up a logic to  print some posts according to the logic.

Comment: In that case send the information to `create` and it route to `index` when you're done.

Comment: It will do that automatically or do I need to explicitly mention that?